# Fixed effects regression drops estimates due to collinearity for more aggregated FE, but not for less aggregated FE

Tags: regression, r, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I am running a fixed effects regression in r using the `fixest` package with a few different settings. I cannot provide data that replicates the errors, as the dataset is too large, and subsets cause other errors, but the general format is the following:

```
library(fixest)

fmla1 <- as.formula("DV ~ factor(Var):(Var2)  + Var2 | state + year")
fmla2 <- as.formula("DV ~ factor(Var):(Var2)  + Var2 | year")
fmla3 <- as.formula("DV ~ factor(Var):(Var2)  + Var2 | state")
fmla4 <- as.formula("DV ~ factor(Var):(Var2)  + Var2 | city + year")
fmla5 <- as.formula("DV ~ factor(Var):(Var2)  + Var2 | city_year")

reg1 <- feols(data = df, fml = fmla1)
reg2 <- feols(data = df, fml = fmla2)
reg3 <- feols(data = df, fml = fmla3)
reg4 <- feols(data = df, fml = fmla4)
reg5 <- feols(data = df, fml = fmla5)
```

Where the fixed effects variable `state` is a factor for the state of the observation, `year` is a factor for year, `city` is a factor for the city, and `city_year` is a factor for the city-year fixed effect. `Var2` is a factor variable with three categories, where the reference level is "a". `Var` is another factor, of integers ranging from -10 to 10. The two are interacted without a baseline estimate for `Var`, because when `Var2` == "a", `Var` is always 0. So to avoid that collinearity, I only produce an estimate for the interaction and for `Var2`.

When I run these models, the first 3 models do not work. I receive an error message like the following:

```
The variable 'Var0:Var2a' has been removed because of collinearity (see $collin.var).
```

However, for `reg4` and `reg5`, no such error is drawn.

I am trying to understand how this can occur, and determine whether the results for `reg4` and `reg5` can be trusted.

As noted above, `Var` is perfectly collinear  for the observations where `Var2` == "a". So I can see how a multicollinearity issue would be caused. But it is also collinear when the City and City-Year fixed effects are used, without any dropping.

City and City-Year are obviously at a lower level than the State fixed effects, which is to say that the City-Year and City fixed effects would be absorbed by state. Therefore, shouldn't the same relationships exist between the variables and the fixed effects under the two specifications? There is no added variation for the collinear cases of Var2 == "a", those pairs are simply divided across more cities than the states, all with the same value.

For additional context, levels of `Var` are assigned to all observations in a given state and year, basedon their level of `Var2`. So, for example, in year 1880, if `Var2` == "b", all these observations have a `Var` of 3. So variation in `Var` occurs at the state level (and by extension uniformly treats all cities within that state).

With this setup, why can I estimate this model with fixed effects at the city level, but not at the state level, when the treatment assignment (values of `Var1`) occurs at the state level? If `Var` drops when it is interacted with `Var2` when there is state FE, shouldn't the exact same happen when city is used, assuming it is a sub-state unit?

If not, can anyone suggest an example where this design would happen and is legitimate?